# How do I map matrices to some integer value?

Tags: c++, dictionary, matrix

For example, I want to map

```
       1  2  3
       3  4  1 -> 0
       1  1  1 

       1  2  3
       1  1  2 -> 1
       1  1  1
```

and so on. Is it possible using std::map?

EDIT: I mean to ask if I have a 2-D array, or an array of 1-D vectors, how do I map it with some integer values.

Comment: How do you represent a matrix in your code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't understand your question?

Comment: How do you store a matrix in your program? Note that "matrix" is a mathematical concept. C++ does not have any type called `matrix`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I store it as a 2-D array. Or an array of vectors in general.

Comment: First, you need to choose one matrix representation and stick with it. A vector of vectors is probably better than an array of vectors. You can also use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` as stated in the answer below. With that in mind, then the direct answer is "yes, you can use `std::map` for your mapping".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::array` of `std::array` like :

```
std::map< int, std::array<std::array< int , 3>, 3> > m = 
{ {0, {{ { 1,2,3},
         { 3,4,1},
         { 1,1,1} 
      }} 
  }, 
  {1, {{ 
         { 1,2,3},
         { 1,1,2},
         { 1,1,1} 
      }} 
  } 
};
```

You may use `std::vector` of `std::vector`, if rows and columns are not known at compile time

```
std::map< int, std::vector<std::vector< int > > > m;
```

---

For opposite mapping matrix to integer you can just reverse the order :

```
std::map< std::array<std::array< int , 3>, 3>, int  > m_opp =
{ { {{ { 1,2,3},
         { 3,4,1},
         { 1,1,1} 
      }}, 
    0 
  }, 
  { {{ 
         { 1,2,3},
         { 1,1,2},
         { 1,1,1} 
      }}, 
    1 
  } 
};
```

or

```
std::map< std::vector<std::vector< int > >, int > m_opp;
```

Comment: How do I add another mapping in this map? I mean how do I add more mapped matrices here?

Comment: @ash Just do `{3, {{ }} }, {4, {{ }} },` etc

Comment: This solution maps an `int` to a matrix. The OP is asking for the opposite mapping.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice to obtain the opposite mapping we can simply do this  :                 std::map< std::array<std::array< int , 3>, 3> , int >  right?

Comment: @ash _"Doesn't work"_ is a very vague response. To me it appears like you're victim of [_XY Problem_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397). Or do you want us to write your code ?

Comment: Hi! When I try to access the mapped value from the key matrix it doesn't seem to work, ex `a={ {1,2,3},{1,1,1},{1,1,1} };   cout<<m[a];` 
It gives compilation error. What's wrong with it?
here is a similar code: [ideone](https://ideone.com/NaHWVX)

EDIT: The previous comment was incomplete. Sorry for that.

Comment: @ash `int a[3]` is not same as `std::array<int,3>` !

Answer (score 0):

> if I have a 2-D array, or an array of 1-D vectors, how do I map it with some integer values.

I assume you mean "map" in the general sense here. You have several options:

1. You can calculate the mapping on the fly with a function.
2. You can store the mapping in an `std::map`.

If you repeatedly perform the calculation on each matrix, then option 2 will use memory to save CPU cycles. If you perform the calculation infrequently, option 1 will use less memory but more CPU cycles. You should implement both and profile your code to measure the exact trade off.

Comment: What does "mapping on the fly" mean?

Comment: @ash It means you can do the calculation as needed. For example if the "mapping" is from a matrix to its determinant.